# How to automatically shutdown Ubuntu when idle?

Tags: shutdown, cron

Hey guys how could I autoshutdown Ubuntu when it is idle for more than 30 minutes?

Autosuspend leaves the PC really slow at times.

Comment: Is this Ubuntu Server or Ubuntu Desktop? Which version are you targeting? Some methods work with specific versions ...

Comment: It is regarding desktop version.

Comment: This is not directly related, but switching over to a SATA SSD plus adding 4GB RAM to the original 4GB gave me tremendous improvement in suspend-resume operations (almost instantaneous from up to a minute) as well as cold boot-up time (less than 5 seconds from over 1 minute). My laptop is a 2012 model Acer (E1-531). OS is presently Ubuntu 20.04. The SSD is a Seagate BarraCuda Q1 240GB. I made a 100 GB partition for root and rest for home.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using a recent version of Ubuntu Desktop, you can configure this pretty quickly using `dconf-editor`. Here's how:

0. Install `dconf-editor` if it is not already present:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install dconf-editor
   ```
1. Open `dconf-editor`:

   [image: Open the Editor]
2. Click the magnifying glass to start a search, and type "sleep-inactive":

   [image: dconf-editor Search Results]
3. Edit the `sleep-inactive-ac-timeout` value to `1800` (30 Minutes):

   [image: Sleep Inactive AC Timeout]
4. Edit the `sleep-inactive-ac-type` value to `shutdown` (or something else you might prefer):

   [image: Sleep Inactive AC Type]
5. Be sure to save your changes.

That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 7):

[matigo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1341800/618353) works and is pretty easy, but if you prefer the command line, you can do the same with the following commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 1800
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'shutdown'
```